# Run first two stages parallelly in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to run the first two stages parallelly in Azure DevOps pipelines? By default, Each stage starts only after the preceding stage is complete unless otherwise specified via the dependsOn property.

Current situation is:

[image]

I would like to run both the stages, iOS_Dev_Build and iOS_QA_Build parallelly. No dependsOn condition is added for iOS_QA_Build. But by default, it is waiting for the iOS_Dev_Build stage to complete before it starts

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please add   `dependsOn: []`    in the  iOS_QA_Build stage.

My example:
[image]

```
stages:
- stage: DEV
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - bash: echo "A"
- stage: QA
  dependsOn: []   
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - bash: echo "A"
```

When you define multiple stages in a pipeline, by default, they run sequentially in the order in which you define them in the YAML file. `dependsOn: []` removes the implicit dependency on previous stage and causes this to run in parallel.

For more details, please refer [Specify dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-dependencies).